# Linking Uploaded File in Phpmailer

Tags: mysql, hyperlink, phpmailer

I'm trying to store links to files uploaded with phpmailer in my MySQL database so that when a web page calls the record, the user can download the files.

My files were getting attached as I want before I added the anchor tag.  Now they no longer get attached to the email, and only the file names are making it into the database.  Am I missing something simple?

```
$mail->AddAttachment("<a href='/home/company/upload/'>".$_FILES['rfile']['name'][0]."</a>");   // add attachments

$mail->AddAttachment("<a href='/home/company/upload/'>".$_FILES['rfile']['name'][1]."</a>");   // add attachments
```

Comment: `['name']` is whatever name the file had on the client's original machine. You need to use `['tmp_name']`, which is where PHP put the file on the server. Of course, that's still pointless, since the upload temp dir is usually somewhere outside of your document root. You need to show your upload-handling code. Because if you're directly storing user files in publically accessible areas, your server is going to get trashed VERY SOON.

Comment: Files are saved to a directory above my webroot.  And the folder does not have execute priviledges.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting HTML into something that's expecting a path to a file? Do this instead (and pay attention to what Marc B said - you should be calling `move_uploaded_file()` somewhere.).

```
$mail->AddAttachment('/home/company/upload/'.$_FILES['rfile']['name'][0]);
$mail->AddAttachment('/home/company/upload/'.$_FILES['rfile']['name'][1]);
```

Comment: @Marc B  Thanks.  Yes, I was trying to wrap the files with links in the wrong place.  No need to have links on attachments.  I think it will work with this:   `echo "<td>" . "<a href='/home/company/upload/" . $row["cover_path"] . "'>" . $row["cover_path"] . "</a></td>";` in the PHP output table's while loop.